# PHP session reset button

Tags: php

i want a button on my website that reads reset, and when clicked the session gets resetted? any ideas? What i mean by resetted is just clears the session, so i want a html button that when clicked just clears the session.

Comment: Reset means what exactly? (Keeps the session going, clears the session, ...?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This button would submit a form to a PHP script that does this:

```
session_start();
session_destroy();

// Typically, after doing this you will redirect the user
// to the home page with something like:
header('Location: index.php');
```

That's all there is to it.

Don't be confused by the "submit a form" part -- you don't *need* to have anything in the form apart from the button.

Comment: or maybe just `session_start(); $_SESSION = array()`.

Comment: But this doesn't actually *reset* a session, it just destroys the current session?

Comment: @MarcB, @Crayon: After destroying the session it's customary to redirect the user as per the PRG pattern. When the new page loads, the session will no longer exist, so there's no need to explicitly unset variables etc.

Comment: John: yes, but setting to a blank array leaves the current session ID intact, but clears out all previous values, which would in effect be a "reset", as the OP wants.

Answer (score 2):

Create a form that contains two things:
1) a hidden var that contains the current URL
2) a button that, when pressed, directs the user to a page that clears the session

on the second page, clear the session and then, using the $_POST information from the form, redirect the user back to the page they were on.

To destroy the session:

```
session_start(); // if it's not already started.
session_unset();
session_destroy();
```

Answer (score 1):

**Easy way (which is almost 100% safe):**
Use javascript to remove the cookie (most of the time PHPSESSID)

**Bit more complicated way (which is far more safe):**
Use PHP to unset $_SESSION (so the user cannot do anything with the PHPSESSID anymore, to prevent hijacking) and then unset or regenerate $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'] (or session_regenerate_id).

Answer (score 1):

This is from the PHP manual for session_destroy:

```
<?php
// Initialize the session.
// If you are using session_name("something"), don't forget it now!
session_start();

// Unset all of the session variables.
$_SESSION = array();

// If it's desired to kill the session, also delete the session cookie.
// Note: This will destroy the session, and not just the session data!
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
}

// Finally, destroy the session.
session_destroy();
?>
```

It first resets all session data (so it can't be used later in the same page load), before removing the session cookie and lastly destroying the session which wil erase the data file from disk.